# How to determine whether an array includes either one of elements

Tags: ruby

I have an array

```
address = ["kuwait", "jordan", "United Arab Emirates", "Bahrain"]
location = "india"
order.country = "jordan" 
address.include? (location || order.country) #=> false
```

My `OR` condition is not working here. Please guide where I am wrong.

Comment: Why is no one pointing out in the answer the error with syntax?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Why your code didn't work**

In following line of code

```
address.include? (location || order.country)
```

first, `location || order.country` is evaluated, which results in `"india"` as per your example. Then it checks if it's present in the address array, essentially making it:

```
address.include? "india"
```

which is `false` and hence you get `false result.`

Similarly if you try:

```
address.include? (order.country || location)
```

it will return `true` as it checks `address.include? "jordan"`. Therefore this is not the correct way to achieve what you are aiming for.

**What is the correct way of using `Array#include` for this example?**

```
address.include?(location) || address.include?(order.country)
```

Comment: This code violates DRY principle. What if there were 3 candidates to check for include? Five? Twenty?

Comment: I understand that. I would have myself suggested using `&` as in your answer. However my answer was focused on explaining what was wrong with current code and how can that be corrected.

Answer (score 7):

There are many ways to achieve this functionality:

```
!(address & [location, order.country]).empty?
(address & [location, order.country]).any?
[location, order.country].any? { |addr| address.include? addr }
```

Your code fails because `location || order.country` is evaluated to `truthy` (the first argument of call to `||` in this particular case, since `"india"` is `truthy`.) While you expect it to be treated as “array includes this or array includes that,” it is in fact “array includes the result of ‘this or that’, which is apparently `"india"` for the example given”.

Comment: `address != address-[location, order.country] `

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more way:

```
address = ["kuwait", "jordan", "United Arab Emirates", "Bahrain"]
to_check = ["india", "jordan"]
p present = (to_check - address).size < to_check.size
#=> true
```